# 2nd network with 10G NIC on vSphere Cluster

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi

I am installing Vsphere 8.0U2 Essential Plus on 3 Dell servers, each having 2x32C AMD CPU, 256GB RAM, 2x1G ethernet port, 2x10G dual port NIC along with 1xME5012 iSCSI storage with direct connectivity. I have used 1 10G NIC for iSCSI SAN. I have installed ESXi, vCenter and configured HA. My planning is using 2x1G nic (in teams) for Management and rest dual port 10G NIC for DATA & live vMotion for the VMs as there will be ERP with SQL DB and few other servers. 2x1G network is working properly(able to ping any network segment, vms are connected with internet etc.), I have checked the live-vmotion and it is successful. On 10G I have created one vswitch with dual uplink with Active/Standby mode (as there is 2xCisco 9300 in HA in the core and my network is terminated on these 2), created 2 portgroups (data & management) and created vmkernel adapter connected with management PG and internal configurations are same with 2x1G configs. But whenever I am creating any vm on this 10G network, it is able to ping other vms who are on this 10G network but unable to connect to internet or other segments of network. Still I have not enabled vMotion as previously I enabled the same with NIC Teaming policy Active/Active and Route based on IP hash, it was not able to connect the other network segments, live vmotion was not happening and due to any unknown reason during my trying to set it right, vcenter got crashed and I have reinstalled it. Now 2x1G part is working satisfactorily with vMotion and Network Connectivity but any way I have to set right this 10G part also. During checking I have found there is no IPv4 routing table entry in default TCP/IP stack for vmk3 which is my 10G network. Can it be the cause of this problem? If so how can I make an entry in this routing table for vmk3? By the way, both 1G & 10G have to be in same IP subnet that is 192.168.201.x.

Please help.

Regards
Somnath Nandy

Comment: Is your router reachable from a VM?

Comment: Having both the management network and the VM network on the same subnet is going to be problematic. You should either separate this or use the same physical link for both.

Comment: On 10G it is not reachable. Planning to go for a new subnet for 10G. Should I put every host one by one into Maintenance Mode and configure the VMK with new subnet or directly configure the VMK from host side without putting them in maintenance mode - confused on this.

Comment: You don't need maintenance mode for this.